# How can i get value from an Rxjs observable in my code?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Hi All I have a small snippet of code which is not compiling. i am using angular 5 , rxjs and typescript in my code.

the error is unable to assign this.account = value . it says value is Observable and it cannot be assigned to this.account which is an Account object.

```
 this.authenticationService.currentUser$.pipe(
  map(  user =>  user.account.id),
  map( id => this.accountService.get(id) )
).subscribe(
 value => { this.account = value }    
);
```

any idea how can i rewrite the code snippet to get it work ?
thank you so much

Comment: Your subscription to authenticationService.currentUser$ will return an observable instead of a value because of your second `map()` returns `this.accountService.get(id)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand `this.accountService.get(id)` returns Observable, in that case you need to use `switchMap()` instead of `map()` operator, otherwise you will get Observable inside subscribe instead of the value that you are interested in.

Your example will become:

```
this.authenticationService.currentUser$.pipe(
  map(user => user.account.id),
  switchMap(id => this.accountService.get(id)),
).subscribe(
 value => { this.account = value }    
);
```

Comment: thank you it works with switch map . imagine what would be the code like if we use map

Comment: Yep, and also you can also use other flat maps, like `concatMap`, `mergeMap`, `exhaustMap`

Comment: thank you so much . very useful tips for newbies like us